# Определить повторный клик на элементе ДОМ

Tags: javascript, counter

Задача такая при повторном клике на элементе не увеличивать счетчик, элементу на котором кликнули присвоен класс .off(cursor-pointer:none;)
но при этом нельзя увеличивать счетчик ходов. В итоге получилась такая функция, которая среди двух элементов всегда ищет идентичный.

````
``` //reduction of the steps to counter
    let reduction = function(array, counter){

     if (array[0].classList == "off" && array[1].classList== "off"){
         if(array[0] === array[1]){
         counter--;
      }

   }

 }```
````

и вот кусок кода, где она вставлена 
    ```if (valueCards.length === 2) {
        reduction(openCards);
        // access to events
        accessEvents = false;

```
    //add function callback (rating)
    let counterFunction = (function(elem = moves) {
    counter++;
    moves.innerHTML = counter;
    //console.log(stars, counter);
    updateStars();
    })();
```

```

Comment: Поставьте клик на элемент у которого нет данного класса, document.querySelector("element:not([class])")

Comment: sorry, это не очень оптимально, есть общая функция которая слушает весь список. Весь код тут: [ссылка](https://github.com/Natanagar/memory-game). Была мысль на какое то время отвязать обработчик